# How to start /stop a windows service through a Windows Form application

Tags: winforms, windows-services

I wish to start and stop another Windows Service application via my WIndows Form application.
Ons tart of my application I wish to start the Windows service, and on application exit I wish to stop the service.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [ServiceController class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx).

Initialize it with your service name, and call Start() and Stop() methods.

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("My service name");
if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
  sc.Start();
}
//etc..
```

Comment: @xaria: Your service might need elevated privileges to be controlled, in this case run you program as administrator

Comment: Yep that was the case. Thanks